# Is there a chance to add a collapsable text via a dedicated button?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

I just started with SwiftUI and wanted to build a simple home app. In order to have a better overview I structured my site using a collapsible view, which when expanded reveals the home view. However, I've been struggling to make a dedicated "plus" button that adds another one of the predefined collapsable views to my Content View

Here is the code I made (with the help of a tutorial) for the CollapsableViewModel:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Button(
                    action: { self.collapsed.toggle() },
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Empty...", text: $textFieldText)
                                .font(.title2.bold())
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: self.collapsed ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.01))
                    }
                )
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                }
                .padding(1)
                
                
                
            }
            VStack {
                self.content()
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none)
            .clipped()
            .transition(.slide)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Content View:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{ 
            HStack{
            CollapsableViewModel(
                label: { Text("") .font(.title2.bold()) },
                content: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("turn off light.")
                        Text("turn on ac.")
                        
                        Spacer()}
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    
                }
                
            )
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
                
            }
            .padding()
                }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .statusBar(hidden: false)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
        
        
            }
```

Now, the problem is that I really don't know where to start with this. My guess is that I have to work with an button that triggers a "showCollapsView" action. But I don't how I make it so that it appears under the VStack of my main ContentView. Any tipps would be appreciated, as I would love to understand this whole process myself!

Comment: On "plus" you add a task model and view should just render corresponding views in ForEach iterating that models, then adding new task will be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! - I think I know how I could do that.